# Only allow generic types that implement attribute

Tags: c#, generics, custom-attributes

Is it possible to restrict a generic type to a class that implements a particular attribute?

If I have an attribute called MyCustomAttribute... I want to write something like this:

```
public class SomeRandomClass<T>
    where T : MyCustomAttribute
{
}
```

but not where T is a derived class of MyCustomAttribute, but a class that implements the attribute.

Thanks

edit:

I mean implemented like this:

```
[MyCustomAttribute]
public class SomeOtherClass
{
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between deriving from class and implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for generic parameter constraint which will require type argument to be marked with some attribute, then its not possible.

Here is list of possible constraints: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). You can add following six constraints for type argument

1. to be a value type
2. to be a reference type
3. to have a public parameterless constructor
4. be or derive from specified base class
5. implement specified interface
6. be or derive from other argument